# I am using Intent to call another Activity and not sure what's the error

Tags: listview, android-intent

I am using intent to call another activity and passing the listview's value to the second activity but getting error on click on the listview selection. Getting

Below is my MainActivity

```
package com.listview_gps;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String [] locations = {
    "KFC",
    "McDonalds",
    "A & W",
    "Burger King",
    "Tesco",
    "Home"
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, locations));
}

public void onListItemClick(
        ListView parent, View v, int position, long id)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, location_gps.class);
    intent.putExtra("Location", locations[position].toString());
    startActivity(intent);
```

}

My Second Activity

```
Package com.listview_gps;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class location_gps extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.locationgps);

    TextView nameView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationgps);
    nameView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("Location"));
}
```

}

My Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.listview_gps.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name = ".location_gps"
        android:label="Location GPS" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name = "com.listview_gps" />
            <category android:name = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        ></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: have you checked for value of 'position',it must be not a valid index for your array 'locations'

Comment: Yes. I got error from this:

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.listview_gps/com.listview_gps.LocationGps}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

the class name should start by capital letter so change your class name location_gps to Location_gps and make sure change is made every where inside manifest also